# Second price auctions for more stable transaction fees

Tags: fees

Why does Ethereum not use a second price auction for setting transaction fees?

This would protect users from [paying too much by mistake](https://medium.com/amberdata/most-expensive-transaction-in-ethereum-blockchain-history-99d9a30d8e02) and lead to more stable and predictable fees for everyone.

Implementing this for Bitcoin is discussed in the paper [Towards a Functional Fee Market for Cryptocurrencies](https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=3318327)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Such a proposal was raised on ethresear.ch in July 2018, and is still under active discussion.

https://ethresear.ch/t/first-and-second-price-auctions-and-improved-transaction-fee-markets/2410

Why isn't this already implemented?

Firstly, it'd require a hard fork. (No big deal; it could go in with the next scheduled network upgrade.)

Secondly, you're changing the incentive system and therefore the cryptoeconomics at play. The current system works and is well understood from a game theory perspective. Changing things would presumably first require drawn-out academic discussion on how best to design an implementation. We're just not there yet.